# Unable to use shared state ViewModel in Koin 2.1.6

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm, koin

I'm using Koin 2.1.6 in my app module. Here are the artefacts I use

```
implementation "org.koin:koin-android:2.1.6"
implementation "org.koin:koin-core:2.1.6"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.1.6"
implementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-fragment:2.1.6"
```

And Koin module is

```
val userModule = module {
   viewModel { (handle: SavedStateHandle) -> UserViewModel(get(), handle) }
}

class UserViewModel(
         val iService: IService, //injected from core module
         val handle: SavedStateHandle
) : ViewModel()
```

I use this `ViewModel` on `UserFragment`

```
private val viewModel: UserViewModel by stateViewModel()
```

`UserFragment` contains an internal fragment- `UserUpdates`, inflated from layout, shares the above `ViewModel`.

```
  <fragment android:name="UserUpdates"
            android:id="@id/fragment_user_updates"
            android:width="match_parent"
            android:height="wrap_content" />
```

On `UserUpdates` fragment, I set the `ViewModel` as follows

```
 private val viewModel: UserViewModel by stateSharedViewModel()
```

However, I found out that ViewModel instances generated are not shared. In fact they are created as new objects. Is there anything I miss out here?

Comment: Just leaving this for ref: https://medium.com/koin-developers/whats-next-with-koin-2-2-3-0-releases-6c5464ae5e3d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use `stateSharedViewModel` (instead of `stateViewModel` you have right now)